# Better way to create immutable object in C++

Tags: c++, class, struct, constants, immutability

I want to create a simple struct / class which will represent some **immutable** plain data.

#### Way 1:

```
struct Immutable {
    Immutable(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    const int a;
    const int b;
};
```

#### Way 2:

```
class Immutable {
public:
    Immutable(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    int getA() const { return a; }
    int getB() const { return b; }
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

The only difference I can see is that the **first way** is simpler and the **second way** is more adapted for potential further class expansion. Are there any more differences (in terms of design, speed, etc.)?

Comment: Since it's just POD the first one makes more sense. Also, you don't need to define a constructor for POD structs that are considered aggregate and can be initialized directly. [Look here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) The struct also more clearly signals that it's just POD.

Comment: Writing extra code "just in case" is a violation of the [YAGNI principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Be prepared for change, but wait for the real requirements.

Comment: Also worth reading imo: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with the second approach. At the moment it's just a POD, but if you wanted to add additional functionality you'd need to do it via member functions, and then for consistency your access to the data is also via methods. For example:

```
class Immutable {
public:
    Immutable(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    int getA() const { return a; }
    int getB() const { return b; }

    int add() const {return a + b}
    int sub() const {return a - b}
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

How you've got a consistent approach, rather than calling methods in some cases, and accessing the fields directly.

Also, by hiding the member fields you're stopping some joker casting away the `const` and modifying the value. I know this is undefined behavior, but there's always someone who thinks they'll do it rather than making a copy of the immutable object. Making it tough for them to do this isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also, good point on the `const_cast`: I didn't think about it.